# Guice injection not working with Dropwizard

Tags: guice, dropwizard

I am new to Dropwizard and Guice, so I followed this tutorial : [Dropwizard and Guice Integration](https://dzone.com/articles/dropwizard-and-guice). When executing the main method, I've got this error:

```
default configuration has an error:
  * message can not be found (was null)
```

So I guess that Guice injection did not work.
I have the exact same code as the tutorial, except that I don't have the `plugins` part in my `pom.xml`, and I have this line in the main method:

```
new ServiceApplication().run(new String[] {"server"});
```

instead of:

```
new ServiceApplication().run(args);
```

Am I missing something? is there anything that I must add?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have missed an important bit.
The article gives the following command for running the `dropwizard` app (please note the string after the `server` option, which points the file with the configuration options):

> $ java -jar target/DropWizardGuice-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server **config.yml**

Also earlier in the article there is a description of the relation between the configuration `.yml` file and `Guice`:

> Now we need a bit of glue code that takes the message from the configuration file to make it available to Guice.

By changing the code in the `main` method to:

> new ServiceApplication().run(new String[] {"server"});

you explicitly refused to provide `dropwizard` information it needs about where the configuration options are (including in your case the value of the `message` property). And that is what the error message says.